# Why did the Conglomerate CEOs conceal their appearance?

Tags: my-dad-the-bounty-hunter

In *My Dad The Bounty Hunter*, both the high-ranking executives of the sinister galactic Endless Horizons Conglomerate that we have seen are secretly some type of lizard alien. Notably, they are *different* types of lizard aliens: while Tim Fixer seemed to be a reptilian humanoid with regenerative abilities who covered his appearance with a thin layer of human skin (metaphorically somewhere between a gecko and a chameleon), Pam had a more sophisticated get-up, being an enormous crocodilian alien compressed into a human-like suit (who naturally was known for her [affected sorrow](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/crocodile%20tears) and [insincere smiles](https://disney.fandom.com/wiki/Never_Smile_at_a_Crocodile)). The executives use these disguises regardless of which species we see them interact with or where they do it.

Now, humans and human-like aliens seem to be a distinct minority in the galaxy (seemingly limited to just two planets, as far as we know), while aliens with distinctly non-human appearances, including some reptilian ones, seem to be widespread, so it is not as if anyone would bat an eye at their true appearance. By contrast, *concealing* their appearance definitely makes them look shady if revealed (in fairness, they *are* shady). Why do the executives of the EHC devote so much effort to disguising themselves as humans?

Comment: Easier on the special effects/costuming budget?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - It is an animated series where most of the characters are aliens.